# C++ trait for "has no constructors" OR trait for "is zero-initializable"?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, c++17, zero

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) says for *zero initialization*:

> Zero initialization is performed in the following situations:
> ...
> 2) As part of value-initialization sequence for non-class types and for members of value-initialized class types **that have no constructors**, ...

What trait or combination of traits can I use to test either for:

- type is zero-initializable with an empty `{}`, or
- class type has "no constructors"

  - (which I *think* means no user-defined constructors?)

(P.S. tagged `C++11` to indicate any "modern C++" approach is acceptable; also tagged `C++17` to indicate the latest C++ version I'd like for an answer.)

(P.P.S. I know cppreference is *not* the standard, but it is almost always correct.  If it is not correct in this case, that should be part of the answer ...)

Comment: I am not sure if this is the correct answer but I am thinking in the direction of : is_trivially_constructible, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible

Comment: What exactly would it matter if a type were "zero initializable"? How would that meaningfully be different from value initializable?

Comment: @NicolBolas - I was under the impression that there was a difference in how padding between members was either initialized or not.  This is a for a serialization system that currently relies on that (mainly to get reliable results during testing, AFAIK, but possibly in some more significant way too).  So .. currently it's being done with `memset` - I want to see it being done with zero-initialization.  I've confirmed (godbolt) that these types _are_ in fact zero initialized (all bytes zeroed including padding) (with this compiler).  I want to `static_assert` that to ensure it stays that way.

Comment: @PepijnKramer - unfortunately `is_trivially_constructible` is too strong - it prohibits member initializers.  Which in this case are all default == zero initializers.  For which you may say: Just get rid of them, then.  But it isn't so easy.  This existing codebase is in the medical devices field and changes are highly restricted.  (The `memset` change I can do because it is arguably _safer_ to be standard compliant rather than `memset` - plus it is in a source file.  The initializers are in a header ... I know, I agree, but these are the rules ...)

Comment: I know about medical restrictions ;) Then have a look at std::is_trivially_copyable (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) and even if you can't use it yet read about C++20's std::bit_cast (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast ) it has some nice things to think about :) Just trying to think along with you (and learn something in the process myself if you don't mind)